# R function to sort data

Tags: r

I have a bunch of stock data in the form of a data.frame (stock_name, Date_time and close price). Currently all the the stock names are in the leftmost column with many repeating themselves, next column has the time and the last one has the close price.

I'd like to change this by having all the dates in the leftmost column the subsequent columns populated by company names and the rest of the cells themselves populated by the close_price.

```
1
Exeter Resource Corp (XRC-T)
2016-05-04 00:00:00
1.15
2
InZinc Mining Ltd (IZN-V)
2016-11-16 00:00:00
0.18
3
Redstar Gold Corp (RGC-V)
2016-07-06 00:00:00
0.05
4
Serengeti Resources Inc (SIR-V)
2016-07-25 00:00:00
0.13
5
Exeter Resource Corp (XRC-T)
2016-05-05 00:00:00
1.13
6
InZinc Mining Ltd (IZN-V)
2016-11-17 00:00:00
0.18
7
Redstar Gold Corp (RGC-V)
2016-07-07 00:00:00
0.05
8
Serengeti Resources Inc (SIR-V)
2016-07-26 00:00:00
0.1
```

*Note I'm a total noob so not too sure where to start. I think I first have to group up the companies and the dates but unsure of the best way to do this.

```
t(stock_price_data)
```

Not currently working

Comment: Explore the functions select and arrange from the dplyr package. You can do it in base R too, using `[<-` and order.

Comment: And, familiarise yourself with this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to swap columns?

For example, you had a dataframe with columns `“a”`, `“b”`, `“c”`, but you want the columns instead to be `“b”`, `“a”`, `“c”`?

If that’s the case, you can do:

```
df <- df[c("b", "a", "c")]
```

Where `df` is the name of your dataframe.